# Org subtree from yasnippet

Tags: org-mode, yasnippet

Can yasnippet be used to insert an org subtree of the same level as the last?  For example, if one often writes

```
***** $1
#+BEGIN_SRC latex
    \paragraph{$1.}
    $0
#+END_SRC
```

how might one avoid having to adjust the number of stars manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can determine the current level within [embedded Emacs-lisp code](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#sec-3-2).

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: org subtree
# key: ost
# --
`(make-string (org-current-level) ?*)` $1
#+BEGIN_SRC latex
    \paragraph{$1.}
    $0
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: This failed with invalid argument (wholep, nil) for me. `(make-string (if (org-current-level) (+ (org-current-level) 1) 1) ?*)` Packing List for $1  [/]` worked for me.