# yassnippet snippet to insert current timestamp

Tags: yasnippet

I would like to create a yasnippet snippet which will insert automatically the current timestamp. I have found a code which actually prints the timestamp but I do not know how to integrate into a yasnippet snippet. 
Any way to do this?

Example. I would like that pressing "weather" and then TAB I get
`2017-07-29, time =`
so I can type the weather.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with this [recent question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34285/org-subtree-from-yasnippet), you can use [embedded Emacs-lisp code](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#sec-3-2).

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# key: weather
# --
`(format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d, time = ")`$0
```