# How to find Emacs Lisp Org Mode functions

Tags: functions, help, commands, apropos

How can I find Org Mode emacs lisp functions like `org-current-level` which is used in the answer for [Org subtree from yasnippet](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34285/org-subtree-from-yasnippet)?

I looked for the command in the [Org Mode Manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Command-and-Function-Index.html) but didn't find it there.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `M-x apropos-function RET org-`.

`C-h f apropos-function` tells you that command `apropos-function` does this:

> **`apropos-function`** is an autoloaded interactive compiled Lisp function
> in `apropos.el`.
>
> `(apropos-function PATTERN)`
>
> Show functions that match `PATTERN`.
>
> `PATTERN` can be a word, a list of words (separated by spaces),
> or a regexp (using some regexp special characters).  If it is a word,
> search for matches for that word as a substring.  If it is a list of words,
> search for matches for any two (or more) of those words.
>
> This is the same as running `apropos-command` with a `C-u` prefix,
> or a non-`nil` `apropos-do-all` argument.

But if you want to know only about Org *commands*, not all Org functions (commands are functions, but not all functions are commands), then use `M-x apropos-command RET org-`.

`C-h f apropos-command` tells you:

> **`apropos-command`** is an autoloaded interactive compiled Lisp function in
> `apropos.el`.
>
> It is bound to `C-h a`, `<f1> a`, `<help> a`, `<menu-bar> <help-menu> <search-documentation> <find-commands-by-name>`.
>
> `(apropos-command PATTERN &optional DO-ALL VAR-PREDICATE)`
>
> Show commands (interactively callable functions) that match `PATTERN`.
>
> `PATTERN` can be a word, a list of words (separated by spaces),
> or a regexp (using some regexp special characters).  If it is a word,
> search for matches for that word as a substring.  If it is a list of words,
> search for matches for any two (or more) of those words.
>
> With `C-u` prefix, or if `apropos-do-all` is non-`nil`, also show
> noninteractive functions.
>
> If `VAR-PREDICATE` is non-`nil`, show only variables, and only those that
> satisfy the predicate `VAR-PREDICATE`.
>
> When called from a Lisp program, a string `PATTERN` is used as a regexp,
> while a list of strings is used as a word list.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to ask Emacs by using "tab completion": `C-h f org-<TAB>` will give you a completion buffer with all the functions that Emacs knows about that start with `org-`. You can click on one to see its doc string. SInce there will be a *lot* of them, you may need to scroll the buffer (just switch to the buffer and use the arrow keys) or refine the search by typing more of the name, e.g. `C-h f org-current-<TAB>`).

The manual does a good job of describing the functions that a *user* should know about, but those tend to be the ones that are bound to keys.

It also describes the most common user options, but it leaves out a lot: one problem with Org mode is that it has too many options :-) Options are implemented as (global) variables and you can get similar help from emacs using `C-h v org-<TAB>` and use the methods above to navigate the completion buffer or refine the search.

Another way to find user options is to say `M-x customize RET` and type `org-` in the search box.

Bon voyage!